# Get values types like similar to JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json, types, stringify

If I `console.log` my array I get this:

```
[ 'query', undefined, [Function] ]
```

However if I `JSON.stringify` the array I get

```
['query',null,null]
```

In most cases this is exactly what you want when converting JSON.

However I was wondering if there was a way to capture a string or array of types as in the first array.

```
someFunc(arr) // '[ 'query', undefined, [Function] ]' (one big string)
someFunc(arr) // [ 'query', 'undefined', '[Function]' ] (array of strings)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can just map the items like this:

```
['query', undefined, function() { }].map(function(item) {
  if (item instanceof Function) return '[Function]';
  if (item === null) return 'null';
  if (item === undefined) return 'undefined';
  return item.toString();
});
```

Comment: Was hoping something existed so I didn't have to consider ever type.